# Detect when I can force unmount usb-otg flash drive after writing file

Tags: android, io, usb-drive

I write file to flash drive:

```
out.write(bytes);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Then I need faster remove usb-org flash drive. And now file not fully written down to flash drive. 
How to detect when file fully written down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than the code you have, assuming `out` is a `FileOutputStream`, do this:

```
out.write(bytes);
out.flush();
out.getFD().sync();
out.close();
```

After `sync()`, the bytes will have been written completely to disk. This puts added emphasis on doing all of this I/O on a background thread, off of the main application thread.